# Thymeleaf template: concatenate Strings

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I have this piece of code, but the option value is not concatenating `{item.id}-${driver.id}` and instead I got "-2"

```
<tr th:each="item: ${devices}" >    

   <td class="col_id"   th:text="${item.id}"  ></td><!-- ID -->
   <td class="col_name"     th:text="${item.description}"></td><!-- NAME -->                                      
   <td class="col_name"     th:if="${#authorization.expression('hasRole(''ROLE_ADMIN'')')}" th:text="${item.application.name}"></td><!-- NAME -->
   <td class="col_name"  >

        <select id="selectAuthorizedDriverId"  >
            <!--  option value="0">Please select the driver</option-->
            <option th:each="driver : ${drivers}" 
                    th:value="${item.id}-${driver.id}" 
                    th:text="${driver.firstName}" 
                    th:selected="${driver.id==item.driverDevices[0].driver.id}">

            </option>
         </select>
```

Comment: An assumption: Thymeleaf is able to do mathematical operations, in your case `th:value="${item.id}-${driver.id}"` will generate a single result from two integers. Try `th:value="|${item.id}-${driver.id}|"` instead as this should make sure the given values are concatenated. Could you check if your value for `item.id` is 2 lower than the value of `driver.id`?

Comment: @SaschaM78, indeed, it work ! please convert to answer

Comment: Great to hear! Sure, I'll create an answer from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf is able to do mathematical operations, in your case:

```
th:value="${item.id}-${driver.id}"
```

will generate a single result from two integers. 
Try

```
th:value="|${item.id}-${driver.id}|"
```

instead as this should make sure the given values are concatenated.